# Getting error after entering a value in a text box in karate UI via Firefox

Tags: firefox, karate

This issue is only when I invoke the scripts via firefox driver, after entering value in a text box getting an error and test is failing

```
configure driver = {type:'geckodriver' , executable:'C:\Users\dinesh\Downloads\geckodriver-v0.31.0-win64\geckodriver.exe'}
driver 'https://courses.ultimateqa.com/users/sign_in'
screenshot()
driver.maximize()
input("//*[@id='user[email]']","abc@gmail.com")
```

Error message

```
* input("//*[@id='user[first_name]']", 'welcome')
js failed:
>>>>
01: input("//*[@id='user[first_name]']", 'welcome')
<<<<
org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: Expected to find an object with property ['message'] in path $['value'] but found 'null'. This is not a json object according to the JsonProvider: 'com.jayway.jsonpath.spi.json.JsonSmartJsonProvider'.
- com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:71)
- com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PathToken.handleObjectProperty(PathToken.java:81)
- com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.PropertyPathToken.evaluate(PropertyPathToken.java:79)
- com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.RootPathToken.evaluate(RootPathToken.java:62)
- com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:99)
- com.jayway.jsonpath.internal.path.CompiledPath.evaluate(CompiledPath.java:107)
- com.jayway.jsonpath.JsonPath.read(JsonPath.java:185)
```

Please help me the xpath is right, karate is writing the value in text box but after that it is failing

Answer (score 1):

For me this code works, both with chromedriver and geckodriver. Of course these executables must be set in the PATH environment variable.
I added also the `waitFor` method to wait for the web element.

```
Feature: sample karate test script
  for help, see: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/IDE-Support

  Background:
    #* configure driver = { type: 'chromedriver', executable: 'chromedriver' }
    * configure driver = { type: 'geckodriver', executable: 'geckodriver' }
    #* def sleep = function(pause){ java.lang.Thread.sleep(pause) }

  Scenario: test error
    Given driver 'https://courses.ultimateqa.com/users/sign_in'
    When waitFor("//*[@id='user[email]']").input('abc@gmail.com')
    And waitFor("//*[@id='user[password]']").input('qwerty1234')
    And waitFor("//input[@type='submit']").click()
    * screenshot()
    #* call sleep 3000
```